Cissoid of Diocles parametric representation
I am trying to find the parametric equations of this geometric form given the definition of: the set of points $P$ that verify $|OP|=|AB|$ where $O=(0,0)$, $A$ is the intersection of the circumference of radius $a$ and centered at $(0,a)$ and the line that passes through $O$ and $P$ and $B$ is the intersection of the same line and the one with constant hight $2a$.
Now, this if we name $P=(x,y)$ and $x=0$ then $y=0$ because $AB$=$0$=$OP$. If $y=0$ then the intersection with the constant line is not defined. So, suppose $y\neq 0$ and $x\neq 0$, then $A=(\frac{2am}{1+m^2},\frac{2am^2}{1+m^2})$ and $B=(\frac{2a}{m},2a)$ where $m=\frac{y}{x}$. Then, $P=B-A=(\frac{2a}{m(1+m^2)},\frac{2a}{(1+m^2)})$
Now, I think I have made a mistake because this is nos the parametric equation I was looking for.
$\textbf{EDIT:} $ I have plotted the curve on Desmos and It was the Cissoid, however, I have not seen this parametrization anywhere, is it right?
Moreover, when I try changing to polar coordinates I get: $\tan({\varphi})=m$ and $r(\varphi)=\frac{2am}{\sqrt{1+m^2}}=\frac{2a\tan({\varphi})}{\sqrt{1+\tan({\varphi})^2}}$. But when I plot this curve, I actually do not get the cissoid. Is there something wrong with my change of coordinates or is it with my initial parametrization?

Your $A=(2a/(1+m^2),2am/(1+m^2))$ traces a circle of radius $a$ centered at $(a,0)$. (Consider where $A$ is for $m=0$.) Swapping the $x$- and $y$-coordinates does what you want (presuming the intended circle is centered at $(0,a)$, as in the definition of the Cissoid, not $(0,2a)$ as stated in your description). Also, why not just define $B=(2am,2a)$ instead of writing $(2a/m,2a)$ "where $m=1/m$"? ... Once you have the proper parameterizations of $A$ and $B$, you can find $P$ via $\overrightarrow{OP}=\overrightarrow{AB}$; that is, $P=B-A$.

@Blue thanks for the answer, I have edited the error you pointed out. And by drawing the $P$ points in geogebra I do get the Cissoid. However, is this parametrization correct? I have not find it anywhere.

The parameterization is correct; it matches the one in Wikipedia's "Construction by Double Projection" section, replacing their $t$ with $1/m$. As for your polar eqn, you seem to have polarized $A$, since the eqn reduces to $r=2a\sin\phi$, which traces the circle. :)  For $P$, you should get $r=2a\cot\phi\cos\phi$. This falls out nicely from right triangles in the figure: If $N=(0,2a)$, then $\angle OBN=\phi$, so $|NB|=|ON|\cot\phi$ (in $\triangle ONB$), and $|OP|:=|AB|=|NB|\cos\phi$ (in $\triangle NAB$).

@Blue Now I got it! thanks. Exaclty as you pointed out, doing the calculations correctly on $P$ gives that the $\tan{\varphi}$ on the numerator $r(\varphi)$ should be on the denominator.

Here's a quick geometric derivation of the polar parameterization, with $\phi$ as the polar angle:

$$r = |OP| :=|AB| = |NB|\cos\phi = |ON|\cot\phi \cdot\cos\phi=2a\cot\phi\cos\phi \tag1$$
The Cartesian parameterization with respect to $\phi$ is then
$$(x,y)=(r\cos\phi,r\sin\phi)=(2a\cot\phi\cos^2\phi,2a\cos^2\phi) \tag2$$
If, as in OP's work, we take $m=\tan\phi$, so that $\cot\phi=1/m$ and $\cos^2\phi=1/\sec^2\phi=1/(1+m^2)$, then the above becomes
$$(x,y)=\left(\frac{2a}{m(1+m^2)},\frac{2a}{1+m^2}\right) \tag3$$
